# Test with anotation @DataJpaTest - EmbeddedDatabaseType is required

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, integration-testing

I want to create test with in memory DB using Spring Boot 1.4.RELEASE. When I added anotation @DataJpaTest to the test and executed the test I'm getting following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: EmbeddedDatabaseType is required; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: EmbeddedDatabaseType is required
```

My Spring boot properties:

```
spring.jpa.database=ORACLE
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=..
spring.datasource.username=..
spring.datasource.password=..

spring.datasource.max-active=20
spring.datasource.max-idle=5
spring.datasource.min-idle=1
spring.datasource.initial-size=5


spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 20000
#spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.validation-query=select 1 from dual;

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=100
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false
```

Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>args4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>args4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.33</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-remote-shell</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.netflix.hystrix</groupId>
    <artifactId>hystrix-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.18</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.perf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>perf4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.reactivex</groupId>
    <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I was expecting that this annotation will replace my real DB with in memory DB.

Answer (score 7):

Resolved by adding dependency to in memory DB:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

EDIT for comment:

In additiona to this I had to turn of hibernate validation in tests.
Added

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

in

test/resources/application.properties

Comment: Did you not have to do anything else to get it to work? I'm having the same issue as you, but when I add the hsqldb dependency I get errors about `org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PG_CLASS`

Comment: I had the same. I had to turn of hibernate validation in tests: added spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop in test/resources/application.properties